# Change iFrame Content based on Time

Tags: javascript, html, time, live-streaming

I am looking to have embedded livestream.com links change with the time, but done in a container on the website, not as an entire page.

So for 6AM-8AM, the embedded content loads "livestream.com/video1"
but at 8AM-3PM, the embedded content loads "livestream.com/video2"

Is this possible without a full redirect?  How would I do this?

Comment: on which language you are developing your back-end ?

Answer (score 0):

You will get the idea

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a')[0].click();
});
var randompage = ['https://www.spirithoods.com/pages/dummypage','https://lifehacker.com','http://www.lipsum.com']

setInterval(function() {
rndm=Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 0 
  $('a').attr('href',randompage[rndm]);
  $('a')[0].click();
}, 5000);
```

```css
.iframes{
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='https://www.spirithoods.com/pages/dummy-page' target='iframename' class='clickit'>hello</a>
<iframe name='iframename' class='iframes'>

</iframe>
```

Comment: Did you get your idea or no help at all give me some respond